# PowerApps - autofill date for newform

Tags: autofill, powerapps

Using PowerApps, how can I get the current date to be autofilled into a new form?

Does the code go into the IconNewItem1 function from the parent BrowseScreen1?

```
NewForm(EditForm1);Navigate(EditScreen1,ScreenTransition.None)
```

as something like ...

```
BrowseGallery1.Selected.Date = Now
```

Or does the code go in the EditScreen1 / EditForm1 area as a rule?

Any guidance or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do that in the form itself (or the date picker control of the form). Select the card that has the date value, and in the right-side pane select the 'Advanced' tab. You'll need to unlock the card to change the properties, and when you do, change the Default property of the card from

```
ThisItem.DateTimeColumn
```

to

```
If(EditForm1.Mode = FormMode.New, Now(), ThisItem.DateTimeColumn)
```

Where `DateTimeColumn` would be replaced with the name of the column in your data source, and `EditForm1` would be replaced with the name of the form control.